# Setting the order of attributes for XML in XSD (XML Schema)

Tags: xml, xsd

Is there any way to set the order of attributes in XML from Schema?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[**Attribute order is insignificant**](http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-xml-20081126/#sec-starttags) per the [**XML Recommendation**](http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-xml-20081126/):

> Note that the order of attribute specifications in a start-tag or
>   empty-element tag is not significant.

**Therefore, XML Schema provides no way to constrain attribute ordering.**

In general, the XML recommendations will all consider attribute ordering to be insignificant, but see the [**section on attribute processing**](http://www.w3.org/2008/xmlsec/Drafts/xml-norm/#sec-Attribute-processing) in the [**XML Normalization Recommendation**](http://www.w3.org/2008/xmlsec/Drafts/xml-norm/) or the [**Canonical XML Recommendation**](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-c14n) if your application has a need for attribute ordering.

Comment: If you are building a tool that is dependant on the order of an XML elements atttributes you are ***Doing it wrong™***

Answer (score 3):

I think it is not possible by means of XML Schema because according [specification of XML](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-starttags) the order of attributes is not significant.