# Attributes are not in order For ComplexType

Tags: xml, xsd, complextype

I am trying to write an XML schema file
where an user can add multiple addresses
I have written fields in this order

```
    Address1

    Address2

    Address3

    AddressType

    City

    State

    Country

    ZIP
```

Iam just writing sample code here.

```
    <complexType name="Addresses_Type">
        <sequence>
            <element name="Address" type="tns:Address_Type" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="1" ></element>
        </sequence>
    </complexType>

    <complexType name="Address_Type">
        <attribute name="Address1"      type="string" use="required"></attribute>
        <attribute name="Address2"      type="string" use="required"></attribute>
        <attribute name="Address3"      type="string" use="required"></attribute>
        <attribute name="AddressType"   type="string" use="required"></attribute>
        <attribute name="City"          type="string" use="required"></attribute>
        <attribute name="State"         type="string" use="required"></attribute>
        <attribute name="Country"       type="string" use="required"></attribute>
        <attribute name="ZIP"           type="string" use="required"></attribute>
    </complexType>
```

But, When user wants to add a new Adress

The fields are coming in different order.
In my case it is happening as following order

```
    ZIP

    State

    City

    Address3

    Country

    AddressType

    Address2

    Address1
```

Why it is giving Attributes in random order.
Is there any way to get the order always what i mentioned in schema.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Setting the order of attributes for XML in XSD (XML Schema)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19263907/setting-the-order-of-attributes-for-xml-in-xsd-xml-schema)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[You cannot enforce the ordering of attributes in an XML document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1682131/can-i-enforce-the-order-of-xml-attributes-using-a-schema).

If ordering is important, you should define these things as elements with content, not as attributes.  Then you can enforce ordering with `<xs:sequence>`.

The order that the attributes are presented to you in will depend on what's in the XML document, and how the parser is implemented that's giving you the attributes.  In any case, you should not rely on the attributes to be presented in some order, even if the documents always provide them in some order.   Further, there's no way for schema to enforce that the documents *must* provide them in some order.